# Reshape vector for given duration values in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have the following vector:

```
x = [6 7 8 9 10 11 17 18 19 20];
```

I have the duration vector, `d`, which counts the elements in `x`:

```
d = [6 4] => d = [x(1:6) x(7:10)];
```

So I want to find the entrances and exits of `d(1)` and `d(2)`:

```
d(1) = x(1:6) => r1 = [6 11];
d(2) = x(7:10) => r2 = [17 20];
```

So finally I want to reshape into the following matrix:

```
result = [r1; r2] = [6 11; 17 20];
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of constructing your result would be to use [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) to help construct your indices.

```
result = x([cumsum([1 d(1:end-1)]); cumsum(d)]).';

    6    11
    17    20
```

If you don't mind breaking this into two lines, you could easily do the same with the following which may be more performant since you're only computing the cumulative sum once.

```
C = cumsum(d);
result = x([1, C(1:end-1)+1; C]).';
```

This constructs a matrix containing the first and last indices of each group specified in `d`. We can then use these to index directly into `x`.

```
starts = cumsum([1 d(1:end-1)])

    1   7

ends = cumsum(d)

    6   10

indices = [starts; ends]

    1   7
    6   10

x(indices).'

    6   11
    17  20
```

Comment: @Bowecho What `out`? You must have caught it between edits.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you changed your answer.